# Why do I have low hot water pressure in showers only?

Tags: plumbing, shower, water-pressure, hot-water

I have 2 showers in my house. Suddenly the hot water pressure dropped in both. The cold is fine and we haven't noticed any change in the faucets in the house. What could make my hot water pressure change from fine one day, then low the next?

We have taken the shower heads off and the water coming out is still low so it's not a blockage in the head.

We also have gas heated water. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: Do the showers have the same valve? Do they have anti-scald mechanisms? A photo of the valves would be helpful, ideally with the covers removed.

Comment: Do you have a hot water tank or do you have a tankless water heater? If you turn on the hot water at the kitchen sink do you get a good flow of hot water?

Comment: What kind of plumbing do you have? Is it PEX (a plastic) and do you have a "manifold" with valves to lines for different use points?

Comment: Do you have a thermostatic mixing valve in a common hot water line for both showers? This is a valve which mixes cold water into the hot so that the water coming out is a safe temperature for the showers.